# List callbacks?

Tags: python, list, callback

Is there any way to make a `list` call a function every time the list is modified?

For example:

```
>>>l = [1, 2, 3]
>>>def callback():
       print "list changed"
>>>apply_callback(l, callback)  # Possible?
>>>l.append(4)
list changed
>>>l[0] = 5
list changed
>>>l.pop(0)
list changed
5
```

Comment: My original answer was also missing `__iadd__` and `__imul__` :).  I've just added them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Borrowing from the suggestion by @sr2222, here's my attempt.  (I'll use a decorator without the syntactic sugar):

```
import sys

_pyversion = sys.version_info[0]

def callback_method(func):
    def notify(self,*args,**kwargs):
        for _,callback in self._callbacks:
            callback()
        return func(self,*args,**kwargs)
    return notify

class NotifyList(list):
    extend = callback_method(list.extend)
    append = callback_method(list.append)
    remove = callback_method(list.remove)
    pop = callback_method(list.pop)
    __delitem__ = callback_method(list.__delitem__)
    __setitem__ = callback_method(list.__setitem__)
    __iadd__ = callback_method(list.__iadd__)
    __imul__ = callback_method(list.__imul__)

    #Take care to return a new NotifyList if we slice it.
    if _pyversion < 3:
        __setslice__ = callback_method(list.__setslice__)
        __delslice__ = callback_method(list.__delslice__)
        def __getslice__(self,*args):
            return self.__class__(list.__getslice__(self,*args))

    def __getitem__(self,item):
        if isinstance(item,slice):
            return self.__class__(list.__getitem__(self,item))
        else:
            return list.__getitem__(self,item)

    def __init__(self,*args):
        list.__init__(self,*args)
        self._callbacks = []
        self._callback_cntr = 0

    def register_callback(self,cb):
        self._callbacks.append((self._callback_cntr,cb))
        self._callback_cntr += 1
        return self._callback_cntr - 1

    def unregister_callback(self,cbid):
        for idx,(i,cb) in enumerate(self._callbacks):
            if i == cbid:
                self._callbacks.pop(idx)
                return cb
        else:
            return None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    A = NotifyList(range(10))
    def cb():
        print ("Modify!")

    #register a callback
    cbid = A.register_callback(cb)

    A.append('Foo')
    A += [1,2,3]
    A *= 3
    A[1:2] = [5]
    del A[1:2]

    #Add another callback.  They'll be called in order (oldest first)
    def cb2():
        print ("Modify2")
    A.register_callback(cb2)
    print ("-"*80)
    A[5] = 'baz'
    print ("-"*80)

    #unregister the first callback
    A.unregister_callback(cbid)

    A[5] = 'qux'
    print ("-"*80)

    print (A)
    print (type(A[1:3]))
    print (type(A[1:3:2]))
    print (type(A[5]))
```

The great thing about this is if you realize you forgot to consider a particular method, it's just 1 line of code to add it.  (For example, I forgot `__iadd__` and `__imul__` until just now :)

**EDIT**

I've updated the code slightly to be py2k and py3k compatible.  Additionally, slicing creates a new object of the same type as the parent.  Please feel free to continue poking holes in this recipe so I can make it better.  This actually seems like a pretty neat thing to have on hand ...

Comment: The callbacks should expect self, the operation, and data relevant to the operation, I think.  Otherwise, very nice.

Comment: @sr2222 -- I think that the callbacks should expect nothing, although it would be easy enough to change for your recommendation (Left as an exercise for the curious reader).  However, supplying additional information to a callback is generally accomplished through closures and `lambda`.  Indeed, I think this is one reason why `lambda` is *so* important in the language.  That's how it's done in `tkinter` for example.

Comment: I'm just thinking of you want to make this useful as more than a toy, your callbacks are going to want to be able to be aware of the list and the things being changed in it.

Comment: @sr2222 -- Maybe.  Making it aware of the list is really easy though:  `A.add_callback( lambda:callback(A) )`.  I suppose having it aware of what is changing is a bit more tricky without changing the framework.

Comment: In 2.x there's also `__setslice__` and `__delslice__`.

Comment: Actually, not really, now that I think about it.  Just do `callback(self, func, *args, **kwargs)` (or maybe `func.__name__`) and your callback knows everything.

Comment: You might also want to override `__getslice__` (and `__getitem__` in 3.x, for `slice` objects) to return a `NotifyList`.

Comment: @eryksun -- That's a reasonable suggestion, and good call on `__setslice__` and `__delslice__`.  I thought those would be handled by `__setitem__` and `__delitem__` (they usually are) ...

Comment: Python 2.x has specific bytecode ops for slicing. The associated sequence methods are deprecated but still used by built-in types. Here's the `assign_slice` function in [ceval.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Python/ceval.c#l4409). It first tries to use the sequence method `sq_ass_slice` (list method `list_ass_slice`), else it builds a `slice` a object.

Comment: @eryksun -- I've updated with your suggestions.  I tested (briefly) with py2k and py3k.  Feel free to edit/comment if you have other suggestions.

Comment: @eryksun -- the existence of the various `__slice__` methods is seeming more stupid by the second.  Anyway, I've updated, added a couple more tests which seem right.  Also I added a way to unregister callbacks that had been registered previously -- It more or less forced me to change the callback list to a dict though (which I'm not terribly happy about).

Answer (score 4):

You'd have to subclass `list` and modify `__setitem__`.

```
class NotifyingList(list):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.on_change_callbacks = []

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        for callback in self.on_change_callbacks:
            callback(self, index, value)
        super(NotifyingList, self).__setitem__(name, index)

notifying_list = NotifyingList()

def print_change(list_, index, value):
    print 'Changing index %d to %s' % (index, value)

notifying_list.on_change_callbacks.append(print_change)
```

As noted in comments, it's more than just `__setitem__`.

You might even be better served by building an object that implements the `list` interface and dynamically adds and removes descriptors to and from itself in place of the normal list machinery.  Then you can reduce your callback calls to just the descriptor's `__get__`, `__set__`, and `__delete__`.

Comment: and `__delitem__` and `pop` and `remove` and `insert`, and `append` and `extend` and `sort` and `reverse` ... That's a lot of work, but at least it's a pretty trivial thing to add...

Comment: @eryksun -- I just saw those on the list of python list methods as well :)

Comment: maybe just modify `__getattribute__` with a list of all relevant functions... ;)

Comment: @pythonm: Just getting the attribute doesn't mean you called the method.

Comment: I meant something like `if attr in self.relevantgmethods: callback();return list.__getattribute__(self, attr)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost certain this can't be done with the standard list.

I think the cleanest way would be to write your own class to do this (perhaps inheriting from `list`).