# Implement a python list with constraints

Tags: python, data-structures

I need a python `list` object which, upon insert, automatically checks for certain constraints of the form: "A must always come before B" or "If C is included, it must always come last".

What's the easiest/fastest way to go about implementing this. The obvious approach is to override all the methods of the list data type which alter its contents (`append`, `extend`, `insert`, etc), and verify that constraints still hold after the operation. It's just that this is pretty tedious as there are a lot of these methods. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Don't forget about `__delitem__` `__setitem__` etc... etc... But you could write a decorator and apply it to each of the mutating methods in a loop (eg, mutates = ['append', 'extend', pop'] etc...

Comment: @mgilson has a very cool example of overriding `list` and adding callback methods to in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259179/list-callbacks. This could perhaps be an interesting use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would strongly recommend subclassing from the `collections.MutableSequence` abstract base class. The drawback is that it won't be recognized as a subclass of `list` (as [user4815162342](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13443454/577088) points out). However, that should almost never matter as long as people using the resulting class are doing the right thing (i.e. using duck typing or passing abstract base classes rather than concrete classes to  `isinstance`).

The wonderful thing about this is that once you've defined the following methods, you get the rest of the [`MutableSequence`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) interface for free. Here's a concrete subclass of `MutableSequence` that you can use as a template for further customization. In your case, you should only have to customize `__init__`, `__setitem__`, `insert`, and `__delitem__`. Everything else is defined in terms of those, and so will perform whatever checks you insert:

```
import collections
class MyList(collections.MutableSequence):
    def __init__(self, it=()):
        self._inner = list(it)
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._inner)
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._inner)
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return item in self._inner
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self._inner[index]
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self._inner[index] = value
    def __delitem__(self, index):
        del self._inner[index]
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'MyList({})'.format(self._inner)
    def insert(self, index, item):
        return self._inner.insert(index, item)
```

A couple of simple tests:

```
>>> ml = MyList('foo')
>>> ml
MyList(['f', 'o', 'o'])
>>> ml.append(5)
>>> ml
MyList(['f', 'o', 'o', 5])
>>> ml.reverse()
>>> ml
MyList([5, 'o', 'o', 'f'])
```

Comment: This approach seems best, as what whitman describes is not a true subtype of list. It will not work in many places a list should.

Answer (score 1):

If your type must be a subtype of `list`, your options are limited. You must subclass list and override the mutator methods, not forgetting the special methods such as `__setitem__`. The bad news is that there is no way to enforce that these methods will be used. Anyone, at any time, can call: `list.append(your_list, new_elem)`, and bypass your `append`. Even worse, Python's implementation does exactly that in places. (This is more often the case with dicts and tuples.)

If your type doesn't need to inherit from `list`, take a look at [`UserList`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/userdict.html#module-UserList) and at [`collections.MutableSequence`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.MutableSequence).

Answer (score 0):

Don't subclass `list`, proxy it: override `__getattribute__` to pass all calls through to the proxied list and then check your constraints.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it won't capture things like `my_list[4] = 6`.