# How do you check if a list has received another value?

Tags: python, list

I would like to be able to know when my list receives another value so I am able to automatically handle that value. Is that possible? If so, how?

For Example:

I have an Entry widget that's state is "readonly", when a new value is added to my_list, I would like to turn the state to "normal" and insert the updated display then set the state back to "readonly"

```
my_list = [3, "+", 4]
display = display = " ".join(str(item) for item in entry_list)
```

Comment: Can you please explain your requirement with an example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List callbacks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259179/list-callbacks)

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of something. It's often just keeping track of the length of the array.

Something like this:

```
oldLength=len(myList)
```

... 
    if len(myList) > oldLength:
        Check new item(s)

Of course this won't work if you're adding new items anywhere (then you'll need to keep track of which item(s) have been added), or if items are being added and subtracted.

A working example would help, as there may be other structures more appropriate for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Let me try this it might work, If not Ill respond with a better example. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure that a value isn't removed and another inserted between checks, you can use the builtin `hash()` function combined with `tuple()`.

However, in this case, subclassing `list` with a callback when it changes might make the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass `list`, override some of its methods to *do stuff* when it changes. -Python 2.7.x

```
class Foolist(list):
    def insert(self, idx, thing):
        super(Foolist, self).insert(idx, thing)
        print('{} inserted at [{}]'.format(thing, idx))
    def append(self, thing):
        super(Foolist, self).append(thing)
        print('{} appended'.format(thing))
    def extend(self, iterable):
        super(Foolist, self).extend(iterable)
        print('{} extended'.format(list(iterable)))
    def __setitem__(self, idx, thing):
        super(Foolist, self).__setitem__(idx, thing)
        print('item[{}] set to {}'.format(idx, thing))
    def __setslice__(self, start, stop, items):
        super(Foolist, self).__setitem__(slice(start, stop), items)
        print('slice({}, {}) set to {}'.format(start, stop, items))
```

Usage:

```
>>> a = Foolist(xrange(4))
>>> a.extend([4,4,4])
[4, 4, 4] extended
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]
>>> a.append(2)
2 appended
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2]
>>> a.insert(-1, 'a')
a inserted at [-1]
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 'a', 2]
>>> a[-1] = 't'
item[-1] set to t
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 'a', 't']
>>> a[1:4] = ['z','z','z']
slice(1, 4) set to ['z', 'z', 'z']
>>> a
[0, 'z', 'z', 'z', 4, 4, 4, 'a', 't']
>>>
```

Instead of print statements you could use a function or logging or a notification ...

Answer (score -1):

I agree with hypogeum about the part of the length of the list, but don't forget to add one to oldLength after you edit your liat and add to it. Because now the oldLength is the current length of your list and you will need it for the next time you will.want to.make the lise editable.